# How do I download a Serilog log file from the current day from my asp.net core web application?

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, ioexception, serilog

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Application. I'm creating a Dev only page that allows me to download the Serilog log file(s).

The log files are on a day rolling interval. I cannot download the current day's file. An IOException is thrown stating the file is being used by another process.

It seems only the log file for the current day is blocked.

Is there a way to release whatever has control on the file, download it, and then re-attach it?

```
public FileContentResult DownloadLog(string name){
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + $"\\Logs\{name}"
byte[] = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path); //Exception thrown here
return File(...);
}
```

Comment: You need to share the code of how you are downloading the file? Are you providing the correct file name to download?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am providing the correct name

Comment: You trying to access the same log file your application is currently writing to. You can try copying the file with some different name before trying to download.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but FWIW you'll often have a better time using one of Serilog's sinks to send the events to a central log server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configure Serilog with `WriteTo.File()`, you need to pass `shared: true` to allow other processes to read it concurrently. I.e.:

```
.WriteTo.File("logs.txt", shared: true)
```